# How to checkout android source from GitHub

Tags: android, github

I want to know how to configure repo tool to download android source from GitHub.

I created the repository for the source code using the repo script

```
repo init --repo_url='https://github.com/android/tools_repo.ig' -u https://github.com/android/platform_manifest.git -b android-4.4_r1
```

When I try to *repo sync*, I got the following error messages:

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/platform/packages/apps/PhoneCommon/' not found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/platform/external/arduino/' not found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/platform/external/chromium-libpac/' not found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/darwin-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7697732/6309), it would be better to use https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest instead of the GitHub one:

```
repo init --repo_url='https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo' -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.4_r1
```

Note: I suppose the `.ig` in "`https://github.com/android/tools_repo.ig`" was a typo.
I also use its android url equivalent instead: https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo

Comment: For some reasons, I must use VPN to access https://android.googlesource.com, so the network quality is very bad, but https://github.com is working well.

Comment: @su-shi I understand, but the GitHub mirrors aren't up-to-date, hence my suggestion.